# Bison/EBNF parse list with at least two elements

Tags: parsing, bison, ebnf, lalr

I am currently trying to parse a comma seperated list with at least two elements using bison.
I know how to parse a list using this:

```
list : list "," element
     | element
```

but how can I make sure that the list has at least two elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the risk of being *two* obvious:

```
list : list "," element
     | element "," element
```